# Can someone help me solve this string index error in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is some code that I need for a schools CAU, I thought I had solved it but I keep getting a string index error, just wondering if anybody could tell me why[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNpUd.png)

```
Letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n","o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

menu = """ 
Caesar Cipher
========================================================
|  To exit the program ---------------------- Enter 0  | 
|  To find your lucky name number ----------- Enter 1  |
\------------------------------------------------------/
"""
option = ""

def lucky_name():




forename = input("What is you forename?")
surname = input("What is your surname?")
forenaem = str(forename)
surnamenum = 0
forenamenum = 0
luckynum = 0
forename = str (forename)
surname = str (surname)
totalnum = 0

while totalnum <= len(forename):

   if forename[totalnum] == Letters[0]:
        forenamenum = forenamenum + 1
   elif forename[totalnum] == Letters[1]:
        forenamenum = forenamenum + 2
   elif forename[totalnum] == Letters[2]:
        forenamenum = forenamenum + 3
   elif forename[totalnum] == Letters[3]:
        forenamenum = forenamenum + 4   
   elif forename[totalnum] == Letters[4]:
        forenamenum = forenamenum + 5
   elif forename[totalnum] == Letters[5]:
        forenamenum = forenamenum + 6
   elif forename[totalnum] == Letters[6]:
        forenamenum = forenamenum + 7
   elif forename[totalnum] == Letters[7]:
        forenamenum = forenamenum + 8
   elif forename[totalnum] == Letters[8]:
        forenamenum = forenamenum + 9
   elif forename[totalnum] == Letters[9]:
        forenamenum = forenamenum + 1
   elif forename[totalnum] == Letters[10]:
        forenamenum = forenamenum + 2
   elif forename[totalnum] == Letters[11]:
        forenamenum = forenamenum + 3
   elif forename[totalnum] == Letters[12]:
        forenamenum = forenamenum + 4
   elif forename[totalnum] == Letters[13]:
        forenamenum = forenamenum + 5
   elif forename[totalnum] == Letters[14]:
        forenamenum = forenamenum + 6
   elif forename[totalnum] == Letters[15]:
        forenamenum = forenamenum + 7
   elif forename[totalnum] == Letters[16]:
        forenamenum = forenamenum + 8
   elif forename[totalnum] == Letters[17]:
        forenamenum = forenamenum + 9
   elif forename[totalnum] == Letters[18]:
        forenamenum = forenamenum + 1
   elif forename[totalnum] == Letters[19]:
        forenamenum = forenamenum + 2
   elif forename[totalnum] == Letters[20]:
        forenamenum = forenamenum + 3
   elif forename[totalnum] == Letters[21]:
        forenamenum = forenamenum + 4
   elif forename[totalnum] == Letters[22]:
        forenamenum = forenamenum + 5
   elif forename[totalnum] == Letters[23]:
        forenamenum = forenamenum + 6
   elif forename[totalnum] == Letters[24]:
        forenamenum = forenamenum + 7
   elif forename[totalnum] == Letters[25]:
        forenamenum = forenamenum + 8
   totalnum = totalnum + 1


totalnum2 = 0    
while totalnum2 <= len(surname):
    if surname[totalnum2] == Letters[0]:
        surnamenum = surnamenum + 1    
    elif surname[totalnum2] == Letters[1]:
        surnamenum = surnamenum + 2
    elif surname[totalnum2] == Letters[2]:
        surnamenum = surnamenum + 3
    elif surname[totalnum2] == Letters[3]:
        surnamenum = surnamenum + 4
    elif surname[totalnum2] == Letters[4]:
        surnamenum = surnamenum + 5
    elif surname[totalnum2] == Letters[5]:
        surnamenum = surnamenum + 6
    elif surname[totalnum2] == Letters[6]:
        surnamenum = surnamenum + 7
    elif surname[totalnum2] == Letters[7]:
        surnamenum = surnamenum + 8
    elif surname[totalnum2] == Letters[8]:
        surnamenum = surnamenum + 9
    elif surname[totalnum2] == Letters[9]:
        surnamenum = surnamenum + 1
    elif surname[totalnum2] == Letters[10]:
        surnamenum = surnamenum + 2
    elif surname[totalnum2] == Letters[11]:
        surnamenum = surnamenum + 3
    elif surname[totalnum2] == Letters[12]:
        surnamenum = surnamenum + 4
    elif surname[totalnum2] == Letters[13]:
        surnamenum = surnamenum + 5
    elif surname[totalnum2] == Letters[14]:
        surnamenum = surnamenum + 6
    elif surname[totalnum2] == Letters[15]:
        surnamenum = surnamenum + 7
    elif surname[totalnum2] == Letters[16]:
        surnamenum = surnamenum + 8
    elif surname[totalnum2] == Letters[17]:
        surnamenum = surnamenum + 9
    elif surname[totalnum2] == Letters[18]:
        surnamenum = surnamenum + 1
    elif surname[totalnum2] == Letters[19]:
        surnamenum = surnamenum + 2
    elif surname[totalnum2] == Letters[20]:
        surnamenum = surnamenum + 3
    elif surname[totalnum2] == Letters[21]:
        surnamenum = surnamenum + 4
    elif surname[totalnum2] == Letters[22]:
        surnamenum = surnamenum + 5
    elif surname[totalnum2] == Letters[23]:
        surnamenum = surnamenum + 6
    elif surname[totalnum2] == Letters[24]:
        surnamenum = surnamenum + 7
    elif surname[totalnum2] == Letters[25]:
        surnamenum = surnamenum + 8
    totalnum2 = totalnum2 + 1

forenamenum = str(forenamenum)
num1 = forenamenum[0]
num2 = forenamenum[1]
num1 = int(num1)
num2 = int(num2)
forenamenum = num1 + num2

surnamenum = str(surnamenum)
num3 = surnamenum[0]
num4 = surnamenum[1]
num3 = int(num3)
num4 = int(num4)
surnamenum = num3 + num4

luckynum = surnamenum + forenamenum

if luckynum >= 10:
    luckynum = str(luckynum)
    num5 = luckynum[0]
    num6 = luckynum[1]
    num5 = int(num5)
    num6 = int(num6)
    luckynum = num5 + num6 

print ("Your name is:") 
print ("Your lucky number is:")
print (luckynum)   
return
```

while not option == "0":
    print(menu)
    option = input("Which option would you like to use? ")

```
if option == "0":
    print("Goodbye!")

elif option == "1":
    lucky_name()

elif option == "2":
    print("Whoops. That menu option doesn't exist.")
    print("Please try again.")
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation

Comment: Why are you using else-ifs? Just use the character code values and math.

Comment: The error message is not from that code. The code raising the exception is not on line 14.

Comment: It's seem the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38307794/can-someone-help-me-solve-this-string-index-error-in-python.

Comment: Do you actually want to do something like `sum([ord(c)-96 for c in 'John Doe'.lower() if 97 <= ord(c) <= 122])`?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong in the `while totalnum <= len(forename):`

The len of an array returns the lenght of an array starting from 1 not from 0.

If you have [1,2,3] the len is 3 but the last position is 2.

So to solve your problem change to this:

`while totalnum < len(forename):`